# Foreach on a RDD distinct does not work

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, distinct-values

I'm trying to concat all distinct values of a Spark RDD, separating them with comma. This is my code:

```
def genPredicateIn(data: RDD[String], attribute: String): String = {
  var s: String = attribute + " in {"
  val distinct = data.distinct
  distinct.foreach(s += ", " + _)
  s += "}"
  s
}
```

But it returns to me just `"attribute in {}"`, why? Which is my mistake?

It works if I write `val array <- data.distinct.collect` and iterate on that. Why?

Comment: If this did work, then you would get `attribute in {, data1, data2}` anyway

Comment: yes that's not my problem

Comment: I don't think a lambda can contain assignment. Why can't you collect the RDD, then do the join? That is essentially what you are doing anyway. The reason you can't do assignment is because Spark can't pass your string to all the worker nodes and concatenate it with the partitions of data

Comment: Ok you're right, thank you!

Comment: K, I use PySpark, so I wasn't sure. I'll answer with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running a similar example on PySpark, I get "lambda cannot contain assignment", so I assume Scala would work the same.

You should be able to `collect` the RDD, and then do the comma-join. That is essentially what you are doing anyway.

The reason you probably can't do assignment is because Spark can't pass your string to all the worker nodes and concatenate it with the diffrent partitions of data, then accumulate the result to pass it back to the running code.